# Dataset creation approach for predicting User Actions

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, feature-extraction, hidden-markov-models, bayesian-networks

I am working on building a model to predict user actions from log data. I have data collected about user actions in multiple sessions for over a year.

I am bit confused about the way to represent logs in form of dataset so as to apply Machine Learning algorithms. I went through couple of research papers where scientists used Bayesian approaches and HMM to represent states of user actions in the dataset. But the issue is that the papers don't go into implementation details.

So my question is - given a set of user actions over time in multiple sessions, how can one create a state transition diagram (or any other representation of user actions) to predict next user action.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Request you to add some sample log data. You may have to do some pre-processing to ensure that you derive features first, and make it ready to be fed into any specific model.

Comment: @Amal : consider any standard Apache Log file. The step I am stuck is which are the features and how to extract them.

Comment: Did you try Splunk or any such log analytics tool? Will post the pointers of any such link here if I get it.